# find or create method in rails not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So i have this in my rake task

```
  Event.find_or_create_by(time: row[9], date: row[10], event_type: word1,  eventimage: row[4], eventname: eventname, eventvenuename: location, event: eventname, eventlink1: eventlink1, eventlink2: eventlink2)
```

Now, I have this loading forma  csv, At the moment, There will be times where the event will be populated then a week later there will be an eventlink2 avalible for the same link.

How can i go about populating eventlink2 if the event is already created? (currently not working)

Sam

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Model.where(thing_to_look_up_by: x).first_or_create(another_thing: y, more_attributes: z)
```

If it doesn't find the thing in the where it will use it in the create.

Comment: So, in relation to the above, If i used `Event.where(event2link: event2link).first_or_create(everything else here?)` what if there was an event link 3? would that be done the same or would i start looking at if else statements

Comment: you can put as many things as you want in the first_or_create...only things in the where clause are going to be used for looking for the object...but if it needs to be created then anything in everything else here will get created.

Comment: @samroberts were you able to figure it out?

Comment: i wont be able to try it out till tomorrow :)

Comment: This didn't work, theres defiantly something that should be there!

Answer (score 0):

For this, I would use :find_or_initialize_by. As params, it takes whatever attributes you want to find_by. My example below finds by the eventlink1 attribute. Make sure whatever attribute you find by is unique across all events.

```
event = Event.find_or_initialize_by(eventlink1: link_1) do |e|
  e.time = row[9],
  e.date = row[10],
  e.event_type = word1,
  e.eventimage = row[4],
  e.eventname = eventname,
  e.eventvenuename = location,
  e.eventlink2 = eventlink2
end
event.save!
```

I also noticed that in your params above you have an :event attribute assigned to an eventname variable. Hopefully this is a typo, the Event model should not have an 'event' attribute. Furthermore, (in your above params) both 'event' and 'eventname' attributes are set to the same variable (eventname). This is wrong (regardless of whether an 'event' attribute really exists or was erroneously included in-place of another. There is no reason to have two columns (event, eventname) that both store the event's name only.

Comment: Hey, Your notice was just a mistake whilst trying to cover up sensitive data :), Like befoe if if i have say 5 eventlinks would i do the above then do the next link then the next?

Comment: I'm not sure what the contents of your CSV file are. What you want to do is create a new event or update an existing even when the csv has a new link for that event. So i'd parse the CSV, iterate thru events and then use find_or_initialize_by.

Comment: Also, bare in mind. With find_or_initialize you're able to fill whatever attributes you want or update the existing values if you wish. Just make sure that you find by a value that is unique to each event (so .find_or_initialize_by(unique_event_identifier: variable).